# Share Image in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, resources, share

I need to share an image (.png format) with transparent background, through sent_action intent.
I searched a lot and tried a lot of samples but couldn't find the solution.
The is this method in witch the image will get shared directly from the resources, but for some reason from some point it has stop working.

```
Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Intent share_intent = new Intent();
    share_intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share_intent.setType("image/png");
    share_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.fromFile(new File(url.toString())));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share_intent, "choose app"));
```

and there is this function which works fine, the problem is it adds a black background to the image.

```
private void share3()
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    OutputStream output;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Gallery/");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "ic_launcher" + ".png");
    try {
        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/png");
        output = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap. compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG/*Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG*/, 0, output);
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "choose app"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need to share the image from "raw" folder in the resources and share it without background. What should I do?

Comment: you are try to share image from drawable folder..???

Comment: drawable or raw doesn't matter. They are the same in addressing.

Comment: what is error in this code..???

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, It is telegram itself. Telegram adds a black background to .png images you share.

Comment: have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..its work for me to share image from drawable folder.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/LatestShare.png";
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file = new File(path);
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    path = file.getPath();
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```

Comment: It still adds a black background to the picture when I share the picture in telegram.